# How to create bound/range interactively/dynamically in a data.table non-equi join?

Tags: r, data.table

Example data:

```
tmp_dt1<- data.table(grp = c(1,2), time = c(0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 0.25, 0.65))
tmp_dt2 <- data.table(grp = c(1,2), time_from = c(0.1, 0.5))

> tmp_dt1
   grp time
1:   1 0.20
2:   2 0.60
3:   1 0.40
4:   2 0.80
5:   1 0.25
6:   2 0.65

> tmp_dt2
   grp time_from
1:   1       0.1
2:   2       0.5
```

I do the following to try and find everything in each group between `time_from` and `time_from + 0.2`, but it errors:

```
> tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, .(grp, time = x.time, time_from, time_to), on = .(grp, time >= time_from, time <= time_from + 0.2)]
Error in `[.data.table`(tmp_dt1, tmp_dt2, .(grp, time = x.time, time_from,  : 
  Column(s) [time_from + 0.2] not found in i
```

I.e. it doesn't like the bound being created within the non-equi join specification. Is there a way to write these bounds interactively, without creating an intermediate variable `tmp_dt2$time_to <- tmp_dt2$time_from + 0.2`?

Comment: I don't think you can, as it stand right now. I believe there is GH issues for that. If not, it should be created as this is a pretty common task.